# How to make the particular column of detail grid editable in kendo

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am developing an asp.net mvc application in which i am using a kendo grid which is new for me. Each grid also consists of detail grid as shown below
[image]

Please, note i marked the column 'LastName' of detail grid. Now, my issue is i want to make this 'LastName' column alone editable. I tried giving "editable:true" but is not working. Please, help me to resove this issue...

```
    function createGrid (element, options) {
    var defaultOptions = {
        detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#detailTemplate").html()),
        detailInit: detailInit,
        columns: [
            { field: "Id", hidden: true, attributes: {class: "idColumn"}, template: '<span data-row-id="#= Id #"></span>' },
            { field: "Name", title: "First Name" },
            { field: "Surname", title: "Last Name",editable:true },
            { title: "", template: '<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selected"></input>' }
        ]
    };
    options = $.extend({}, defaultOptions, options);

    element.kendoGrid(options);
}
```

Here is sample fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/redaemn/BvwMD/

Comment: i updated your code : http://jsfiddle.net/chanaka1/BvwMD/85/ . if you need to stop other fields from editing you should specify it in the datasource model as editable:false

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i want to make the "LastName" column alone editable and FirstName Column should be a readonly field but in your updated code i able to edit both firstname as well as lastname

Comment: i don't know how to achive that with the observable , with kendo dataSource you can achieve that with the schema Model

Comment: can you define it like this .. var viewModel = kendo.observable({
  gridSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: data,
    schema: {
      model: {
        fields: {
          company: { type: 'string' },
          os: { type: 'string' }
        }
      }
    }
  })
});

Comment: Sorry , If i am doing wrong i tried like below as you mentioned http://jsfiddle.net/BvwMD/86/ o